# mock request module with jest - timeout error

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have the following piece of code in my app

request.ts

```
import request from 'request'

export const funcA = async ( apiToken: string, body: any): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: `https://any_url?api_token=${apiToken}`,
            body: {
                ...body,
            },
            json: true,
        }
        request(options, (err, resp, body) => {
            if (err) {
                log('funcA', err)
                reject(err)
            } else resolve(body)
        })
    })
}
```

test.ts

```
import { funcA } from '../funcApath'
import request from 'request'

jest.mock('request')

describe('funcA test', () => {
    test('should call funcA example', async () => {
        const options = await optionsConstructor()
        const mockRequest = await request(options)
        const body = await bodyConstructor()
        const apiToken = 'any_apiToken'
        const result = await funcA(apiToken, body)
        expect(mockRequest).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
})
```

my error:

thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

I already used the "function [beforeEach](https://jestjs.io/docs/api#beforeeachfn-timeout)" to try solve the problem, but doesn't work. Any suggestions? Tks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When mocking the request, you need to make sure your mock still calls the call back provided or your promise will never be resolved.

In your test.ts

```
import { funcA } from '../funcApath'
import request from 'request'

const mockRequest = jest.fn().mockImplementation((options, cb) => cb());
jest.mock('request', () => (options, cb) => mockRequest(options, cb));

describe('funcA test', () => {
    test('should call funcA example', async () => {
        const options = await optionsConstructor()
        const response = await request(options)
        const body = await bodyConstructor()
        const apiToken = 'any_apiToken'
        const result = await funcA(apiToken, body)
        expect(mockRequest).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
})
```